# Trigging events in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is there a way to invoke a certain event [events] before some certain function calls in CodeIgniter ?!
From what i read about hooks ... they seem fine but they are executed before/after a WHOLE controller is being called . I'm looking for something similar but on a function level NOT controller level .

Comment: Where do you want to add the events? If you want something executed after certain functions you could try adding your own parent controller.

Comment: i'm trying to create a general events system where anything could be executed after/Before a certain function

Comment: why not just write a custom helper and call that as and when is needed?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Hooks are predefined points in your application which allows you to do something at that point.

Hooks cannot know which function you are about to run or have run - you need to tell the application by yourself. Either in the functions or before/after calling the functions yourself.